# Where should you put you cache for ensembl-vep using conda

Tags: conda, bioinformatics, vep

I've installed vep in conda like so:

```
conda install ensembl-vep=105.0-0
```

And then I installed the human cache like so:

```
vep_install -a cf -s homo_sapiens -y GRCh38 -c /mnt/gpfs/live/rd01__/ritd-ag-project-rd018o-mdflo13/refs/vep --CONVERT
```

But when I try and run vep I get an error:

```
vep --dir_cache /mnt/gpfs/live/rd01__/ritd-ag-project-rd018o-mdflo13/refs/vep \
   -i /mnt/gpfs/live/rd01__/ritd-ag-project-rd018o-mdflo13/data/test/manual/results/variants/cohort.norm_recalibrated.vcf \
   -o /mnt/gpfs/live/rd01__/ritd-ag-project-rd018o-mdflo13/data/test/manual/results/variants/cohort.norm_recalibrated_vep.vcf
```

Am I doing something wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this working. The cache went into the vet home directory like so:

```
vep_install -a cf -s homo_sapiens -y GRCh38 -c /mnt/gpfs/live/rd01__/ritd-ag-project-rd018o-mdflo13/refs/vep —CONVERT
```

And the I got yep working like so:

```
vep --cache --dir_cache "/mnt/gpfs/live/rd01__/ritd-ag-project-rd018o-mdflo13/conda/envs/bioinfo/share/ensembl-vep-105.0-0" \
   -i "/mnt/gpfs/live/rd01__/ritd-ag-project-rd018o-mdflo13/data/test/manual/results/variants/cohort.norm_recalibrated.vcf" \
   -o "/mnt/gpfs/live/rd01__/ritd-ag-project-rd018o-mdflo13/data/test/manual/results/variants/vep_output.txt"
```